# Can I hide or ignore symlinks with Samba

Tags: backup, samba, symlink

I'm trying to back up our company's website using a regular old windows copy utility.  Website is riddled with symlinks and if they were all followed would bloat the backup to 400% of it's normal girth.

I've told Samba not to follow symlinks, but copying the folders errors out really quick.  Maybe it's the copy util's fault. Maybe it's the server's fault (har har).  Anybody thought of a workaround, besides chmodding all my symlinks to make them transparent to the backup user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Samba is displaying but not following the symlinks and it's just windows explorer that can't handle the resulting permission denied errors, perhaps you can just use the command line  (e.g. xcopy /S or [cwRsync](http://www.itefix.no/cwrsync/)) where the errors will be non fatal.  Alternatively if you can also connect to the server via SSH, SCP/SFTP clients like WinSCP are certainly smart enough to actually handle symlinks sanely as part of a recursive transfer.

Comment: +1 Something like SCP or rsync is much better suited to this problem.